# multiply two consecutive times in assembly language program

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, multiplication

I am using 8086 emulator and DOSBOX and MASM.

I know that when we multiply 8-bit with 8-bit, answer will be of 16-bit.

```
al*(8-bit)=ax
```

And when we multiply 16-bit with 16-bit,answer will of 32-bit.

```
ax*(16-bit)=dx & ax
```

But if the answer is in `(dx & ax)` and I want to multiply 8-bit or 16-bit number then it will simply perform with ax But I needed to multiply a number with answer in `(dx & ax)`. So how to overcome this problem?

I need solve this situation for the factorial program. Where I am trying to find the 10!

Comment: I didn't understand a thing of what you're asking...

Comment: Wants to know how to further multiply a 32 bit value in dx:ax that came from a previous multiplication.  Oops, 10! already doesn't fit in 16 bit so yeah.

Comment: You want to multiply a 32-bit number (DX:AX) with a 16-bit number (AX) in a 16-bit system (MS-DOS). Right? Please tell us your assembler (TASM, MASM, NASM or...).

Comment: @Jester how to do that?

Comment: @rkhb i am using MASM

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure there is a duplicate of this somewhere already. Of course it's just elementary maths anyway:

```
result_low = low(input_low * factor)
result_high = high(input_low * factor) + low(input_high * factor)
```

Pay attention to saving `ax` and `dx` as necessary.

Comment: could you plz write the ALP of this...it would be so kind of you.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have to do it in the decimal system, e.g. `37 * 8`. You would calculate and add two terms: `30 * 8` + `7 * 8`. The first term can be transformed to `3 * 8 * base (10)`.

```
37 * 8
------
 56    (7*8)
24     (3*8)
======
296
```

You see the place of "base" is empty since this value is always 0.

Now let us change base 10 to base "register":

```
DX:AX * CX
----------
   DX:AX  (AX*CX)
DX:AX     (DX*CX) 
==========
XX:XX:XX
```

You need two multiplications and three words for the result. Furthermore you have to store the result (DX:AX) from the first multiplication because you need the registers for the second multiplication.

Here's the code for 10! I omit the leftmost word of the result since it isn't needed for 3628800:

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 1000h

.DATA
Result DD 1                             ; 01 00 00 00 (little endian!)

.CODE

main PROC
    mov ax, @DATA                       ; Initialize DS
    mov ds, ax

    mov cx, 2                           ; Start value

    L1:

    mov ax, WORD PTR Result + 0         ; Low word
    mul cx
    mov di, dx                          ; Store high result
    mov WORD PTR Result + 0, ax         ; Low result won't be changed anymore

    mov ax, WORD PTR Result + 2         ; High word
    mul cx
    add ax, di                          ; add low result from last mul to low result here
    mov WORD PTR Result + 2, ax         ; Store it

    ; adc dx, 0                         ; this would store the "highest" word of result (13!)
    ; mov WORD PTR Result + 4, dx

    add cx, 1
    cmp cx, 10
    jbe L1                              ; While CX <= 10

    mov ax, 4C00h
    int 21h
main ENDP

END main
```