# Multiplying 32 bit two numbers on 8086 microprocessor

Tags: assembly, multiplication, x86-16

I have code example for multiplying two 16 bit numbers on 8086 and trying to update it for two 32 bit numbers multiplying.

```
start:
 MOV AX,0002h ; 16 bit multiplicand
 MOV BX,0008h ; 16 bit multiplier
 MOV DX,0000h ; high 16 bits of multiplication
 MOV CX,0000h ; low 16 bits of multiplication
 MOV SI,10h ; loop for 16 times

LOOP:
 MOV DI,AX
 AND DI,01h
 XOR DI,01h
 JZ ADD
CONT:
 RCR DX,1
 RCR CX,1
 SHR AX,1
 DEC SI
 CMP SI,0
 JNZ LOOP
 JMP END ; ignore here, it's not about multiplication. 
ADD:
 ADD DX,BX
 JMP CONT
```

Code statements above multiply two 16 bit numbers.

To update it for 32 bit two numbers, I know I need updates like:

1. Change `AX` to `00000002h` and `BX` to `00000008h`.
2. Use two more registers (I don't know which registers I should use) to hold second and third 16 bits of multiplication (because multiplication will be 64 bit. 16 bit for 4 times. I currently have DX and CX.)
3. Update loop number to `20h`(`SI` in that case) (that makes 32 times for 32 bit number)

8086 is 16-bit microprocessor so its registers are. I can't assign registers 32-bit-long numbers.

8086's registers:

```
REG: AX, BX, CX, DX, AH, AL, BL, BH, CH, CL, DH, DL, DI, SI, BP, SP.
SREG: DS, ES, SS, and only as second operand: CS.
```

Source: http://www.electronics.dit.ie/staff/tscarff/8086_instruction_set/8086_instruction_set.html

My questions are:

1. How can I handle two different registers for one 32-bit number. (registers are 16-bit, so I have to split the number into two registers)
2. What registers can I use for that purpose? Am I free to use **any** register arbitrarily?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess it's a homework-style problem as otherwise you'd probably reuse some already written and tested code. If it is a homework, then see [Stack Overflow: How can I multiply and divide using only bit shifting and adding?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776211/how-can-i-multiply-and-divide-using-only-bit-shifting-and-adding) and try to figure out how would you implement "big numbers" on [Z80](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zilog_Z80) processor if you were the original ZX Spectrum ROM author. Combine. Done

Comment: to multiply two 32-bit numbers you need 64-bit destination to store the result. It's four 16-bit registers. consider storing result in memory

Comment: I don't understand what does it have to do with Z80 and the stackoverflow link you provided. The stackoverflow link does not give any information about any of my questions. @xmojmr

Comment: It is what I already typed in my question. I have no problem on algorithm, I have problem on coding. I don't know how to use (and which registers) to multiply 32 bit two numbers. @AlexanderZhak

Comment: The `8086` processor already had the `MUL` instruction. If you can not use it then I though the approach used by ZX Spectrum ROM BASIC interpreter might be useful. `Z80` is an 8-bit processor with instruction set similar to the `8080`-up family. ZX had `calculator` routines capable of doing floating point arithmetic using numbers much larger then may fit to single register (a number is byte array). You may find the commented disassembly listing using `Assembly File Listing ROM for the ZX Spectrum` web-search query. It's a worth-reading assembly masterpiece. I'm sorry if not helping

Comment: Are you required to do this bit-wise, or are you allowed to use `mul`?

Comment: If you can use MUL, then port this 32-bit mode 64x64 => 128b function to 16-bit: http://www.plantation-productions.com/Webster/www.artofasm.com/Linux/HTML/AdvancedArithmetica2.html.  (And optimize out the silly stuff, like pushfd to save CF).  It only takes 4 `mul` instructions + some ADC to implement double * double => quad register-width multiplication, and should be *much* faster than an RCR loop.

Answer (score 6):

Give a man a fish and blah-blah-blah…

It’s good, that you have a code example. But do you understand the algorithm?

Okay, let’s go through it step by step on a simplified example: multiplying two 8-bit registers in `AL` and `AH`, and storing the result in `DX`.

BTW, you can use any registers you like unless this or that instruction requires any particular register. Like, for example, `SHL reg, CL`.

But before we actually start, there’re a couple of optimizations for the algorithm you provided. Assembly is all about optimization, you know. Either for speed or for size. Otherwize you do bloatware in C# or smth. else.

```
MOV DI,AX
AND DI,01h
XOR DI,01h
JZ ADD
```

What this part does is simply checks if the first bit (bit #0) in `AX` is set or not.
You could simply do

```
TEST AX, 1
JNZ ADD
```

But you only need to test one bit, thus `TEST AL, 1` instead of `TEST AX, 1` saves you one byte.

Next,

```
RCR DX,1
```

There’s no need in rotation, so it could simply be `SHR DX, 1`. But both instructions take the same time to execute and both two bytes long, thus doesn’t matter in this example.

Next,

```
DEC SI
CMP SI,0
JNZ LOOP
```

Never ever compare with zero after `DEC`. It’s moveton! Simply do

```
DEC SI
JNZ LOOP
```

Next,
Unnecessary loop split

```
JZ ADD
CONT:
. . .
JMP END
ADD:
ADD DX, BX
JMP CONT
END:
. . .
```

Should be

```
JNZ CONT
ADD DX, BX
CONT:
. . .
END:
. . .
```

Here we go with a bit optimized routine you have:

```
LOOP:
 TEST AL, 1
 JZ SHORT CONT
 ADD DX, BX
CONT:
 RCR DX, 1
 RCR CX, 1
 SHR AX, 1
 DEC SI
 JNZ LOOP
END:
```

That’s it. Now back (or forward?) to what this little piece of code actually does. The following code sample fully mimics your example, but for 8-bit registers.

```
 MOV AL,12h   ; 8 bit multiplicand
 MOV AH,34h   ; 8 bit multiplier
 XOR DX, DX   ; result
 MOV CX, 8    ; loop for 8 times

LOOP:
 TEST AL, 1
 JZ SHORT CONT
 ADD DH, AH
CONT:
 SHR DX, 1
 SHR AL, 1
 DEC CX
 JNZ LOOP
END:
```

This is a [Long Multiplication algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Long_multiplication)

```
 12h = 00010010
               x
 34h = 01110100
       --------
       00000000
      01110100
     00000000
    00000000
   01110100
  00000000
 00000000
00000000
```

Add shifted 34h two times:

```
0000000011101000
+
0000011101000000
----------------
0000011110101000 = 03A8
```

That’s it!
Now to use more digits you use the same approach. Below is the implementation in fasm syntax. Result is stored in `DX:CX:BX:AX`

```
Num1    dd 0x12345678
Num2    dd 0x9abcdef0

 mov si, word [Num1]
 mov di, word [Num1 + 2]
 xor ax, ax
 xor bx, bx
 xor cx, cx
 xor dx, dx
 mov bp, 32

_loop:
 test si, 1
 jz short _cont
 add cx, word [Num2]
 adc dx, word [Num2 + 2]
_cont:
 rcr dx, 1
 rcr cx, 1
 rcr bx, 1
 rcr ax, 1
 rcr di, 1
 rcr si, 1
 dec bp
 jnz short _loop
```

Cheers ;)

Comment: BTW, this is shift-right approach is a reversed implementation. Normally people do shift left

Comment: Just for fun, I tested this (in a 64-bit Linux program that checks the result against a 64-bit `imul` and exits 0 or 1.  https://pastebin.com/pjfwFYna).  I didn't have to change any code, since you don't use any 16-bit addressing modes or anything.  It works correctly, so IDK what the user who posted the other answer is talking about.  (If they were even talking about yours.)  And BTW, `RCR reg, 1` is slower than `SHR reg, 1` on modern CPUs like Intel Sandybridge.  I guess you were talking about actual 8086.  I assume this was slower than 4x MUL + some ADC even on 8086, though...

Answer (score 1):

Solution n. 2 seems that not work if the product is large more then 32 Bit.
Furthermore the shift instructions are wrong.
This solution work correctly:

```
Procedure _PosLongIMul2; Assembler;

{INPUT:

 DX:AX-> First factor (destroyed).
 BX:CX-> Second factor (destroyed).

 OUTPUT:

 BX:CX:DX:AX-> Multiplication result.

 TEMP:

 BP, Di, Si}

Asm

     Jmp   @Go

 @VR:DD    0      {COPY of RESULT     (LOW)}
     DD    0      {COPY of RESULT    (HIGH)}

 @Go:Push  BP

     Mov   BP,20H {32 Bit Op.}

     XOr   DI,DI  {COPY of first op.  (LOW)}
     XOr   SI,SI  {COPY of first op. (HIGH)}

     Mov   [CS:OffSet @VR  ],Word(0)
     Mov   [CS:OffSet @VR+2],Word(0)
     Mov   [CS:OffSet @VR+4],Word(0)
     Mov   [CS:OffSet @VR+6],Word(0)

 @01:ShR   BX,1
     RCR   CX,1

     JAE   @00

     Add   [CS:OffSet @VR  ],AX
     AdC   [CS:OffSet @VR+2],DX
     AdC   [CS:OffSet @VR+4],DI
     AdC   [CS:OffSet @VR+6],SI

 @00:ShL   AX,1
     RCL   DX,1
     RCL   DI,1
     RCL   SI,1

     Dec   BP
     JNE   @01

     Mov   AX,[CS:OffSet @VR]
     Mov   DX,[CS:OffSet @VR+2]
     Mov   CX,[CS:OffSet @VR+4]
     Mov   BX,[CS:OffSet @VR+6]

     Pop   BP

End;
```

This works between two unsigned integer.

If you want to multiply a 32 Bit unsigned integer for a 16 Bit unsigned integer, you can use the Mul instruction as follow:

```
Function Mul32Bit(M1:LongInt;M2:Word):LongInt; Assembler;

Asm
 LEA   SI,M1
 Mov   AX,[SS:SI]
 Mov   CX,[SS:SI+2]
{CX:AX contains number to multiply by}
 Mov   BX,M2
{BX contains number that multiply}
 Mul   BX
 XChG  AX,CX
 Mov   SI,DX
 Mul   BX
 Add   AX,SI
 AdC   DX,0
{DX:AX:CX contains the result of multiplication}
 Mov   DX,AX
 Mov   AX,CX
{DX:AX contains the partial result of m. and is the function's result}
End;
```

Comment: @Alexander's answer works for me, with his test inputs (result = `0xb00ea4e242d2080`). Note that he's producing the result in `dx:cx:bx:ax`,  which is a different order from your more-sensible choice of `BX:CX:DX:AX`.  His code assembles the same in 64-bit mode so I just put `shl edx, 16` / `mov dx, cx` / ... / `shl rdx, 16` / `mov dx, ax` after the loop, and use 2 loads + `imul rax, rcx` to check the result against a 64-bit hardware multiply.

Comment: BTW, a 32x32 => 64b multiply using 16x16 => 32b `mul` should only take 4 `mul` instructions (and some ADC).  Here's a 64x64 => 128b example for 32-bit mode (using HLA syntax or something, and probably with more MOV than needed to spill/reload.  http://www.plantation-productions.com/Webster/www.artofasm.com/Linux/HTML/AdvancedArithmetica2.html).

Comment: Thank you for read, excuse me for that I said, I thought that your algorithm could have only one shift instruction that could been substituted (ShR <-> RCR), but I was wrong.
I've not tested your solution and i quickly read it.
I've never think to add only 32 bit factor, because it must been shifted into 64 Bit variable.
It is very quick and uses a best system to shift to right the the factor instead that to left!

Answer (score 1):

**For the record, 8086 has a [`mul` instruction](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mul) that makes this much easier (and more efficient on later CPUs with fast `mul`).**  On original 8086 it was really slow, but running an RCL multi-precision shift loop 32 times sucks a lot on all CPUs!  This version has less static code size, which is nice.

You only need three `mul` instructions to get the `low*low`, `low*high`, and `high*low` products.  (And if you wanted the full 64-bit result, another one for the `high*high` product).

8086 is missing the efficient `imul reg, reg` form that doesn't need DX:AX as an implicit output, and that doesn't waste time putting the high half anywhere.  So unfortunately we need more register shuffling than a compiler would for a 64x64 => 64 multiply in 32-bit mode, but otherwise this is exactly the same problem.  (See https://godbolt.org/z/ozSkt_)

`x_lo`, `x_hi`, `y_lo`, and `y_hi` can be memory relative to `bp` as locals or function args, or labels.  Or some of those could be in registers that this function doesn't use, if you change the syntax so they're not addressing modes.

```
;; untested
;; inputs: uint32_t x, y in memory
;; clobbers: CX, SI, DI

    mov     ax, [y_lo]
    mov     cx, ax
    mul     word ptr [x_hi]
    mov     si, ax            ; save  y_lo * x_hi

    mov     ax, [x_lo]
    mov     di, ax
    mul     word ptr [y_hi]
    add     si, ax            ; sum of the cross products

    mov     ax, di
    mul     cx                ; DX:AX = y_lo * x_lo
    add     dx, si            ; add the cross products into the high half
;; Result: uint32_t DX:AX = X * Y
```

To use fewer tmp registers, you could just reload x_lo and y_lo from memory twice each instead of saving them in DI and CX.

(Related: a [64x64 => 64-bit multiply in 32-bit mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87771/how-can-i-multiply-two-64-bit-numbers-using-x86-assembly-language/23588103#23588103) which is the same problem with different operand size, starting with all 4 values in registers and using `xchg` to manage things.)

Note that we don't save the high-half DX results of either `lo * hi` product because we only want a 32-bit result, not a full 32x32 => 64-bit result.  The low 16 bits of those products add into the top half our our final 32-bit product.  (And we don't need carry-out from them into the top-most 16-bit word of a 64-bit result, so we can add them before the last mul.)

- [Assembly multiplication of 16-bit x 32-bit => 48-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40310666/assembly-multiplication-of-16-bit-x-32-bit-48-bit) shows how `adc` works to propagate results
- **[multiply two 32-bit numbers to get a 64-bit number, on a 8086 (32x32 => 64-bit with 16-bit multiplies)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451628/multiply-two-32-bit-numbers-to-get-a-64-bit-number-on-a-8086-32x32-64-bit-w)** if you *do* need the high half.
- [Multiplying 64-bit number by a 32-bit number in 8086 asm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55485709/multiplying-64-bit-number-by-a-32-bit-number-in-8086-asm/55486908#55486908) shows bigger case, how the pieces fit into the total sum.

A 16 * 32 => 32-bit multiply would be even easier, just two `mul` and one `add` (plus a bunch of `mov` to get data into the right places).  See for example a factorial loop that does this: [multiply two consecutive times in assembly language program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28681607/multiply-two-consecutive-times-in-assembly-language-program/28683170#28683170)  (that answer also shows how extended-precision multiply math works, the same way you add terms for the paper & pencil algorithm for doing multiplication on numbers of multiple decimal digits.)