# Computing the factorial of 10 using 8086 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I have been trying to solve this using assembly language. The thing is I cannot store the 10! In `al` and my code works for finding factorial of 5. How do I store my result of 10! In a register? When I find factorial of 5 I can see the result clearly in `al` because 120 can be stored in `al`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my code for 5!

```
 org 100h
.DATA
ANS DB ? 
.CODE
MAIN PROC
    MOV AX,@DATA
    MOV DS,AX
    MOV AL,5                     
    MOV CL,4
    MOV BL,AL
    SUB BL,1
    L:
    MUL BL
    SUB  BL,1
    LOOP L

    MOV ANS,AL
    END MAIN
ret
```

Comment: Well, indeed, 10! cannot be represented by a 16-bit-wide register. You need to either use some sort of 32-bit-related facilities of 8086 (if the ISA has any), or alternatively - compute the lower and the higher 16-bits separately, in two registers.

Comment: 10! = 0x375f00, and even 9! is 0x58980, so you couldn't just loop upward.  But 8! is only `0x9d80` so you could `inc bx` / `mul bx` inside a loop that ends with `DX:AX = 0x58980` as the output from `9 * 0x9d80` with a 16-bit `mul`.  So you can do that and then you're one extended-precision multiply away from the right answer if you loop as far as you can with `inc bx` / `mul bx`.   You can do the times 10 as `(x << 1) + (x<<3)`.  e.g. see discussion in comments on [Shift right by half a bit](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/472043) for a 64-bit (in 16-bit mode) multiply by 10.

Comment: BTW, your current code is pointlessly complicated, and if you need large number obviously you should be using full-width registers.  If you start with CX = AX-1, a loop that does `mul cx` / `loop` would work for small inputs.  No need to use another down-counter as well.  (But like I said, you want the last multiply to be by a larger number so the double-width result of the last `mul` might not overflow.)

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: The answers there are over-complicated because they avoid the hardware `mul` instruction for no apparent reason.  A 16 x 32 => 32-bit product on x86 only takes 2 `mul` instructions for low * low and low * high, and one add.  (And more `mov` or `xchg` instructions because we don't have `imul reg, reg` for the high half.)

Comment: @PeterCordes OK, I've deleted the comment with the link  to that question/answer.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: I looked but didn't have much luck finding a 32x32 => 32 Q&A for 8086, only 64x64 => 64 or 128 for 32-bit mode.  Just for fun I'm writing a `mul` answer for [Multiplying 32 bit two numbers on 8086 microprocessor](//stackoverflow.com/q/29246857)

Answer (score 2):

I tried to explain the algorithm to multiply a dword by a word in a 16-bit environment here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28683170/3512216

An implementation that computes 10! and works also in EMU8086:

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 1000h

.DATA
decstr DB 16 DUP ('$')                  ; String is $-terminated

.CODE

main PROC
    mov ax, @DATA                       ; Initialize DS
    mov ds, ax

    mov bx, 10                          ; Factorial 10! = 3.628.800
    xor dx, dx                          ; DX:AX=1 (first multiplicand)
    mov ax, 1                           ; Begin with 1

    ; for (dx:ax = 1, cx = 2; cx <= 10; cx++)
    mov cx, 2                           ; Incrementing multiplicator
    L1:
    call mul_dword_word                 ; DX:AX * CX -> DX:AX
    inc cx
    cmp cx, bx
    jbe L1                              ; While cx <= 10

    ; Print result
    mov di, OFFSET decstr
    call dword_to_dec
    mov dx, OFFSET decstr
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h

    ; Exit
    mov ax, 4C00h
    int 21h
main ENDP

mul_dword_word PROC                     ; DX:AX multiplicand, CX multiplier
    push dx

    mul cx                              ; AX * CX -> DX:AX
    mov si, dx                          ; Store high result
    mov di, ax                          ; Low result won't be changed anymore

    pop ax                              ; High word
    mul cx                              ; AX * CX -> DX:AX
    add ax, si                          ; Add high result from last mul to low result here
    adc dx, 0

    mov si, dx                          ; SI:DX:AX return value
    mov dx, ax
    mov ax, di
    ret                                 ; RET: SI:DX:AX result
mul_dword_word ENDP

dword_to_dec PROC                       ; ARG DX:AX DWORD, DI: offset of string

    mov cs:target, di
    mov si, ax
    mov di, dx

    ; First Loop: get digits and push them
    mov cs:counter, 0
    mov bx, 10
    LL1:
    inc cs:counter
    xor dx, dx
    mov ax, di                          ; High WORD
    mov cx, ax
    div bx                              ; DX:AX / BX -> AX Remainder DX
    mov di, ax                          ; Store new high word
    mul bx                              ; AX * BX -> DX:AX
    sub cx, ax                          ; sub highest CX-divisible value

    mov dx, cx
    mov ax, si                          ; Low WORD
    div bx                              ; DX:AX / BX -> AX Remainder DX
    or dl, 30h                          ; Convert remainder to ASCII
    push dx                             ; Store remainder
    mov si, ax                          ; Store new low WORD

    or ax, di                           ; Anything more to process?
    jnz LL1                             ; yes: jump to LL1 above

    ; Second Loop: get back digits in reversed order
    mov di, cs:target
    mov cx, cs:counter
    LL2:
    pop ax
    mov [di], al
    inc di
    loop LL2
    mov BYTE PTR [di], '$'              ; Terminator for INT 21h/09h

    ret
    counter dw 0
    target dw 0
dword_to_dec ENDP
```

Comment: You don't need a 48-bit product to hold `10!`.  And taking an arg in DX:AX is actually *less* convenient.  I found when writing [Multiplying 32 bit two numbers on 8086 microprocessor](//stackoverflow.com/a/60015995) that it seems easier to do the low x high cross product(s) first so you can do the low x low last.  For your loop I think that would save on `mov` instructions, and you already produce the result in regs other than si:dx:ax so you need 3 `mov` at the end which you could avoid with a different choice.

Comment: @PeterCordes: `mul_dword_word` is a reusable (and reused by me) function. 32-bit multiplied by 16-bit can result in a 48-bit integer. It would not be serious if the multiplication returns only a part of the possible results. Of course the function can be trimmed for the respective purpose - but that should be the task of the OP. At the moment you can compute with it up to 17!. A screen output for an 48-bit number would be interesting.

Comment: @PeterCordes: The next step would be a BigNumber implementation. According to my feeling it is then easier to start with the lowest values. If you think you have a better algorithm, you are free to post another answer. I myself have found a lot of theory but hardly any useful examples so far.

Answer (score 2):

`10!` is `10*9*8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1`.

For speed you can minimize the size of intermediate values by doing them in "big * little" pairs, like `(1*10) * (2*9) * (3*8) * (4*7) * (5*6)`.

You can describe these pairs as the expression `temp = x * (11 - x)` (with values of `x` from 1 to 5). If you know the result for `x` (e.g. `temp = 10` if `x == 1`) then the result of the next pair can be derived from the result of the previous pair. E.g.:

```
temp1 = x * (11 - x)

temp2 = (x+1) * (11 - (x+1))
      = (x+1) * (11 - x - 1)
      = x * (11 - x - 1) + (11 - x - 1)
      = x * (11 - x) - x + (11 - x - 1)
      = temp1 - x + (11 - x - 1)
      = temp1 - x - x + 11 -1
      = temp1 - (x << 1) + 10
```

In other words; if you know that the result of "pair 1" (or `1*10`) will be 10, then you can calculate the result of the next pair (or `2*9`) by doing `(10) - (1<<1) + 10 = 18;`, then calculate the result of the next pair by doing `(18) - (2<<1) + 10 = 24`, then...

Note that there is no multiplication involved for calculating the pairs this way. After calculating the intermediate results from pairs (with add/sub alone), you end up with "`10! = 10*18*24*28*30`".

For more fun; you can prove that all of these intermediate results will always be even. That means you can cheat and say "`10! = 10*18*24*28*30 = 5*9*12*14*15 << (1+1+1+1+1) = 5*9*12*14*15 << 5`"; which is important when you're looking at doing more expensive "too big" multiplications later.

Because these intermediate values fit in 8 bits, we can do "pairs of pairs" just with two 16-bit multiplications. "`10! = (5*9) * (12*14) * 15 << 5 = 45 * 168 * 15 << 5`".

By multiplying the smallest intermediate values the result will still fit in 16 bits. "`10! = 45 * 168 * 15 << 5 = (45*15) * 168 << 5 = 675 * 168 << 5`".

Now you only need to do one multiplication where the result is 32 bits but both operands are 16 bit. Real mode handles this perfectly fine with a single `mul` instruction so that is no problem; it's just that the result will be stored in `dx:ax`. Specifically, for 675 * 168 the result in `dx:ax` will be 113400 (or 0x1BAF8, or 0x0001 in `dx` and 0xBAF8 in `ax`).

This gives us "`10! = 113400 << 5`". For this it'll be a little awkward on an old "16-bit only" CPU (where you can't just use 32-bit instructions in real mode, including 32-bit `mul`). The best way for 8086 is probably using another register for a "right shift then `or`" to get the bits from `ax` into `dx`; like:

```
mov cl,5
mov bx,ax
shl dx,cl
shl ax,cl
mov cl,16-5
shr bx,cl
or dx,bx
```

For 80186 and later you can do it slightly better using "shift by immediate" to avoid using `cl`, like `shl dx,5`, but that isn't supported for 8086.

The result will be 3628800, which is the right answer.

Note that this same approach can be tweaked to handle other factorials - for odd factorials you can ignore the `*1` that doesn't actually do anything to ensure the intermediate results from pairs are still even (e.g. "`11! = 1 * (2*11) * (3*10) * (4*9) * (5*8) * (6*7) = (2*11) * (3*10) * (4*9) * (5*8) * (6*7)`"). For all factorials (`n!`); the intermediate calculation of pairs can be described as `temp2 = temp1 - (x << 1) + (n & (~1))` (I think - didn't actually check); and the final shift will always be `n/2` rounded down (e.g. for `11!` the shift count will be "`(int)11/2 = (int)5.5 = 5`).

With 16-bit multiplication alone it should be good up until 15!. For 16! and larger, the same techniques work to minimize the number of 32-bit multiplications needed.

Comment: `shld` is a 386plus-only instruction.

Comment: @ecm: Ah - you're right (thanks!) - fixing

Answer (score -1):

It's because `AL`, `BL`, and `CL` are of 8 bits, but what you require is a 16-bit register. This can be done by replacing all `L` with their `X` counterparts. Although doing so won't help in storing 10! (which requires even more than 16-bits), but we can find 8!, for example (i.e. anything which can be stored in 16-bits).

```
org 100h

.DATA                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
ANS DB ?
.CODE



MAIN PROC
  MOV AX, @DATA
  MOV AX, 8
  MOV CX, 7
  MOV BX, AX
  SUB BX, 1

  LOOP_LB:
  MUL BX
  SUB BX, 1
  LOOP LOOP_LB
END MAIN

ret
```

The screenshot of the output:
[image: screenshot of the output]

Comment: The `loop` instruction and a separate CX counter is kind of pointless; you could just use `jnz` to keep looping while BX != 0.  Or maybe better, `dec bx` / `cmp bx, 1` / `ja LOOP_LB` to not re-run the loop for BX=1, saving an iteration and avoiding truncating the last DX:AX multiply result to 16-bit.